# How to find which protocol is used by lower layers?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip, layer

When we type https://stackoverflow.com/ all the data which is sent to this server would be using HTTPS protocol in transport level

So is it possible for me to know which error detection, flow control or protocols, in general, are used by lower ( physical, data link, network ) layers by my machine and intermediate nodes which lie in path from my machine to the destination server (Assuming there are few intermediate nodes) .

Comment: *"...how does one know..."* - who is "one"? At which position in the network is "one"? What data can "one" access? And what is the actual problem "one" wants to solve?

Comment: I have edited the question, sorry for ambiguity

Comment: May have better luck posting at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To figure out what kind of lower layers are used, I always use WireShark.

Start the Wireshark, type "tls" as the filter(because this is no "https" filter in WireShark),  you will get a lot of network traffic, just looks like this:

[image]

Check the details of the "Application Data" network packet,

[image]

You will see the network stack(From top to down):

1. Transport Layer Security (TLS): It's used to securely transmit data above TCP connection
2. Transmission Control Protocol (TCP): It's used to reliably transmit data between two network applications running on two different hosts connected by the internet. [Transport Layer]
3. Internet Protocol (IP): It's used to transmit data between hosts connected by the internet. [Network Layer]
4. Ethernet II:  it's used to transmit data on the underlying Ethernet physical layer transport. [Data Link Layer]

You can check the details by selecting any one of them.

For "error detection", "flow control", you may filter the network traffic by the TCP filter provided by Wireshark,

such as:

```
"tcp.analysis.retransmission", 

"tcp.analysis.window_full", 

"tcp.analysis.window_update",

and so on.
```

If you have a good understanding of TCP, you can read them easily.:)

Comment: But wireshark will just give the information about  my machine.....what about intermediate devices like routers, switches, etc....also could we know what physical layer protocol is used ... Thanks in advance 

Comment: That is really beyond what I know, but interesting;). Let me know if you got any real answers to that. Maybe you need to learn some router protocols likes OSPF，RIP .... Logs produced by the intermediate devices may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You usually cannot get such low level information from other devices in the path of the data. You can get some layer 2 information inside the local network but from devices after the router (i.e. outside the LAN) such data are no longer accessible.

Sometimes one can make some assumptions based on detected MTU in the path (PMTU), latency issues, buffering behavior or based on strange issues caused by known behavior anomalies or peculiarities of some devices, but there is no generic way to access such lower level information.

Comment: Does intermediate nodes like router, switches, etc mutually decide what protocol to use in a a particular layer.

Comment: IP traffic is done at OSI layer 3 and is kept at this layer. The devices don't "decide" about the lower layers, this is simply the hardware they have, i.e. Ethernet, serial line, ...